# Swift delegate does not inherit NSObject

Tags: ios, swift, generics, delegates, nsobject

I am trying to implement some sort of delegate broadcaster (Observer Pattern) in Swift to register multiple delegates. To use the "isEqual" function I need the generic to inherit from NSObject

To avoid duplicate code I prepared a generic DelegateBroadcaster:

```
import UIKit

class DelegateBroadcaster<T : NSObject>: NSObject {

var delegates : [T]

override init() {
    delegates = []
}

func addDelegate(newDelegate : T) {
    delegates.append(newDelegate)
}

func removeDelegate(oldDelegate : T) {
    for i in 0...delegates.count-1 {
        if (oldDelegate.isEqual(delegates[i])) {
            delegates.removeAtIndex(i)
            break
        }
    }
}

}
```

and subclass this for any specific broadcaster.

```
import UIKit

class NavigationControllerBroadcaster : DelegateBroadcaster<UINavigationControllerDelegate> {

}
```

**But I get a strange error: "DelegateBroadcaster requires that 'UINavigationControllerDelegate' inherit from NSObject"**

This is strange because the class reference by apple ([Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/)) says that UINavigationControllerDelegate inherits from NSObject.

So why do I get an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing class `NSObject` ([NSObject class)](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/) and protocol `NSObject` ([NSObject protocol](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSObject), in Swift called `NSObjectProtocol`).

`UINavigationControllerDelegate` is a protocol and cannot inherit from class `NSObject`, it inherits from `NSObjectProtocol` (switch your documentation to Swift, you will see the difference).

Comment: Anyway, I switched the inheritance to NSObjectProtocol and now it works.

**Apparently I can use protocols as generic types**

Answer (score 0):

`UINavigationControllerDelegate` is not a concrete type, it is a Protocol and therefore cannot be used as the type signature for the `DelegateBroadcaster`

Comment: As I commented on Sulthan's answer, it is possible